# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when building Azure JAVA function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to build a JAVA  based Azure function that has a maven jar dependency  of json simple 1.1.1

I have added the MAVEN dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

in the POM and when I build the code using mvn clean package, I am getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:0.1.7:package (package-functions) on project oktaAPI: Execution package-functions of goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:0.1.7:package failed: A required class was missing while executing com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:0.1.7:package: org/json/simple/JSONObject
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:0.1.7
```

I have tried mvn clean and mvn clean install commands but to no use. I also tried deleteing the .m2 folder and build the function again, but the issue persists.